# Which statistical test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am designing my study, but I am a little stuck in which test I eventually should use. I have a between-subject design with 6 conditions (let's say A, B, C, D, E, F), with each having 6 responses (let's call these a, b, c, d, e, f), on a 7-point scale:

```
IV (condition) -> DV
A -> a, b, c, d, e, f
B -> a, b, c, d, e, f
C -> a, b, c, d, e, f
D -> a, b, c, d, e, f
E -> a, b, c, d, e, f
F -> a, b, c, d, e, f
```

So, each condition has 6 dependent variables. I don't want to test difference between the conditions, but only the effect of the condition on the different DV's. For example, when someone is in condition A, I would expect them to score higher on DV a than on DV b, c, d, e, and f. When someone is in condition B, I would expect them to score higher on another DV, and so forth.

Later on, I expect also some moderator effects, but I guess that's only adding interaction terms to the model.

Can I use separate tests for each condition? Or should I test it in one big model? What kind of test would be most suitable for this. Most tables that should help you choose a statistical test only show options with 1 DV.

Comment: Do you expect what happens under each condition to be independent of what happens under every other condition?

Comment: Yes, I expect what happens under each condition to be independent.

Comment: Would a MANOVA be the right choice here?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please clarify you variable and their measurement scale?

**6 conditions (let's say A, B, C, D, E, F)** represents 6 input variables or 6 categories of one input variable.

**Each having 6 responses (let's call these a, b, c, d, e, f), on a 7-point scale**. Is it one outcome variable measured on 7-point likert scale or 6 outcome variables (each measured on 7-point likert scale)

Techniques which can be used:

6 inputs, 6 outcomes - multivariate multiple regression or MANCOVA

1 input (with 6 categories), 6 outcomes - multivariate regression or MANOVA

6 inputs, 1 outcome - multiple regression

1 input (with 6 categories), 1 outcome - simple regression with dummy variable or ANOVA